# The importance of brackets

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning javascript basics through code school.com, and i am having difficulty understanding some basic things.

Within this code:

```
var numSheep = 4;
var monthsToPrint = 12;

for (var monthNumber = 1; monthNumber <= monthsToPrint; monthNumber++) {

  if (numSheep > 10000) {
     numSheep / 2;

    console.log("Removing " + numSheep + " sheep from the population.");}


  numSheep *= 4;
  console.log("There will be " + numSheep + " sheep after " + monthNumber + " month(s)!");
}
```

Why does the bracket after `(numSheep > 10000)` change my output so much?

Sorry for the simple question, and thank you for your patience.

Comment: use an editor correctly indenting your code you will show block of code

Comment: Apart from Javascript, do you have any knowledge on other scripting/ programming languages?  If yes, then you shouldn't need to ask these very basic things...

Comment: are you asking about the closing bracket  ')'? or entire bracket in 'if' condition?

Comment: You have to use the curly braces : **`{ }`** if your `if` statement contains more than one line

Comment: Perhaps your real problem is that you calculate numSheep/2 but don't assign it to anything - you probably intended `numSheep = numSheep/2`

Comment: Take a deep look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An if statement consists of three things

1. The keyword `if`
2. A condition `(foo)`
3. The code that will be executed if the condition is true

That code can be either a statement or a block.

**Statement**

```
if (1) 
    console.log("If is true");
console.log("This is a new statement and not part of the if");
```

**Block**

```
if (1) {
    console.log("If is true");
    console.log("This is in the block so is part of the if");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`numSheep / 2;`
is not a valid javascript code.

It should be like `numSheep = numSheep / 2;`

If condition contains more than one line of code then it must be in { } curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The bracket after allows multiple statements to be executed as part of the 'if'. Without the bracket after the 'if', only the first statement after it is included as part of the 'if'.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

In this line bracket decide the boundary of If() condition and more than one line of code in if() condition  then it want bracket

```
 if (numSheep > 10000) {
         numSheep / 2;
         console.log("Removing " + numSheep + " sheep from the population.");
    }
```

if you only have single line on code then you don't want bracket after if() condition

like that

```
if (numSheep > 10000) 
         numSheep / 2;
```